# Get list of filenames from a remote directory FTP SSH

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssh, sharpssh

I need to get the list of all the filenames through SFTP with VB. I'm trying to place it in an ArrayList, but unsure on the commands to use..

```
Public Shared Function Retrieve_Directory_list(ByVal strHost As String, _
                                ByVal strUsername As String, _
                                ByVal strPassword As String, _
                                ByVal strFtpFilePath As String, _
                                ByVal strlocalFilePath As String) As ArrayList)

    Dim sshCp As SshTransferProtocolBase
    Dim res As New ArrayList()

    sshCp = New Sftp(strHost, strUsername, strPassword)

    sshCp.Connect()

'res = sshCp.???


    sshCp.Close()

Return res

End Function
```

Please let me know if u need anything else.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably going to want to look at Tamir.SharpSsh.Sftp.GetFileList(String path) which returns an IEnumerable of objects that represent remote files. It should be able to do what you're looking for.

https://bitbucket.org/mattgwagner/sharpssh/src/260e9d6d1bcf/SharpSSH/Sftp.cs

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
sshCp.Connect()

Dim result as ArrayList() = sshCp.GetFileList("/foldername")

sshCp.Close()

Return res
```